# jQuery .submit() ignored on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, submit

I've got a form that I want to submit through jQuery ajax. It works in all the browsers except on the iPad/iPhone. I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. The iPad completelly ignores the call from ajax and just "submits" the form.

Here's the java for that particular part (it's placed inside document ready):

```
$(".add_to_cart").bind('submit', function(e) {

var productID = $(this).attr('id');
var quantity = $(this).find("#quantity").val();


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/add/',
    data: 'quantity='+quantity+'&product_id='+productID,
    success: function(callback) {
            window.location = '/cart/';
    }

});

e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here's the html

```
<form id="481" class="add_to_cart" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="481">
<select name="quantity" id="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

I've tried live, bind and also submit(). In this sample I've got bind, but that's also not working on the iPad, or any other iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

It might actually be "working" but getting an error.

In fact even a syntax error somewhere in your function would stop the prevent default from working.  That is why you always see the `e.preventDefault();` as the first line in the function.  This is what I suggest you do first.

In addition the ajax call could be giving an error too, use an error handler to know for sure:

```
 error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working yet. I moved up the e.preventDefault();. Also I added the error handler and no errors are displayed.